# Oracle SQL, take current month's values from the previous month if they are not available yet and return it along with the previous month's values

Tags: sql, oracle, missing-data

I want to generate a report for item prices for all previous and current months. However, the current month's item prices will not be available in the system until after the 10th of every month. So until the records become available, the query should take the previous month's price for the current month.

For example here is the table for item prices:

[image]

Assuming the current date is May 3rd, the query should return the following:

[image]

If the query runs after May 10th and the current month's prices are present for May, it should return what it finds:

[image]

Comment: Are you really storing these dates as month names?

Comment: It is not my actual data or table.  Those snippets are dummy tables for clarification only.  come on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `DATE` column is a `DATE` data type that is set to midnight of the 1st day of each month then you can use:

```
SELECT item, "DATE", price
FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT item, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), price
FROM   table_name
WHERE  "DATE" = ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
AND    EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) < 10;
```

*Note: `DATE` is a reserved word and you should not use it as a column identifier; if you do then you will need to use quoted identifiers wherever you reference it.*